# Killing node with __consumer_offsets leads to no message consumption at consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have 3 node(nodes0,node1,node2) Kafka cluster(broker0, broker1, broker2) with replication factor 2 and Zookeeper(using zookeeper packaged with Kafka tar) running on a different node (node 4).

I had started broker 0 after starting zookeper and then remaining nodes. It is seen in broker 0 logs that it is reading __consumer_offsets and seems they are stored on broker 0. Below are sample logs:

Kafka Version: **kafka_2.10-0.10.2.0**

```
    2017-06-30 10:50:47,381] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Loading group metadata for console-consumer-85124 with generation 2 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
    [2017-06-30 10:50:47,382] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Finished loading offsets from __consumer_offsets-41 in 23 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
    [2017-06-30 10:50:47,382] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-44 (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
    [2017-06-30 10:50:47,387] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Finished loading offsets from __consumer_offsets-44 in 5 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
    [2017-06-30 10:50:47,387] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-47 (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
    [2017-06-30 10:50:47,398] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Finished loading offsets from __consumer_offsets-47 in 11 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
    [2017-06-30 10:50:47,398] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-1 (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
```

Also, I can see GroupCoordinator messages in the same broker 0 logs.

```
[2017-06-30 14:35:22,874] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to restabilize group console-consumer-34472 with old generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
    [2017-06-30 14:35:22,877] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Group console-consumer-34472 with generation 2 is now empty (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
    [2017-06-30 14:35:25,946] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to restabilize group console-consumer-6612 with old generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
    [2017-06-30 14:35:25,946] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Group console-consumer-6612 with generation 2 is now empty (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
    [2017-06-30 14:35:38,326] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to restabilize group console-consumer-30165 with old generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
    [2017-06-30 14:35:38,326] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Group console-consumer-30165 with generation 2 is now empty (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
    [2017-06-30 14:43:15,656] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 3 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
    [2017-06-30 14:53:15,653] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
```

While testing *fault tolerance* for the cluster using **the kafka-console-consumer.sh and kafka-console-producer.sh**, I see that on killing broker 1 or broker 2, the consumer can still receive new messages coming from producer. The Rebalance is happening correctly.

However, killing broker 0 leads to no new or old messages consumption at any number of consumers. 
Below is the state of topic before and after broker 0 is killed.

**Before**

```
Topic:test-topic    PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,0   Isr: 0,2
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0,1
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 2    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
```

**After**

```
Topic:test-topic    PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,0   Isr: 2
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 1
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 2    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
```

Following are the WARN messages seen in the consumer logs after broker 0 is killed

```
[2017-06-30 14:19:17,155] WARN Auto-commit of offsets {test-topic-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=4, metadata=''}, test-topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=5, metadata=''}, test-topic-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=4, metadata=''}} failed for group console-consumer-34472: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing offsets. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2017-06-30 14:19:10,542] WARN Auto-commit of offsets {test-topic-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=4, metadata=''}, test-topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=5, metadata=''}, test-topic-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=4, metadata=''}} failed for group console-consumer-30165: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing offsets. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```

**Broker Properties**. The remaining default properties are unchanged.

```
broker.id=0
delete.topic.enable=true

auto.create.topics.enable=false
listeners=PLAINTEXT://XXX:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://XXX:9092
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-test1
num.partitions=3
zookeeper.connect=XXX:2181
```

**Producer properties**. The remaining default properties are unchanged.

```
bootstrap.servers=XXX,XXX,XXX
compression.type=snappy
```

**Consumer properties**. The remaining default properties are unchanged.

```
zookeeper.connect=XXX:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.id=test-consumer-group
```

As far I understand, if node holding/acting GroupCoordinator and __consumer_offsets dies, then the consumer unable to resume normal operations in spite of new leaders elected for partitions.

I see something similar posted in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362911/kafka-high-level-consumer-error-code-15/42416232#42416232). This post suggests to restart the dead broker node. However, there would be delay in message consumption in-spite of having more nodes until broker 0 is restarted in production environment.

Q1: **How can the above situation be mitigated ?**

Q2: **Is there a way to change the GroupCoordinator, __consumer_offsets to another node?**

Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the replication factor on the __consumer_offsets topic. If it's not 3 then that's your problem.

Run the following command `kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic __consumer_offsets` and see if in the first line of output it says "ReplicationFactor:1" or "ReplicationFactor:3".

It's a common problem when doing trials to first setup one node and then this topic gets created with replication factor of 1. Later when you expand to 3 nodes you forget to change the topic level settings on this existing topic so even though the topics you are producing and consuming from are fault tolerant, the offsets topic is still stuck on broker 0 only.

Comment: Thank Hans. I didn't changed the replication factor of default topic created. I will try the suggestion

Comment: I understand you didn't change the replication factor but if you did any pub/sub on a one node cluster first, before expanding the cluster to 3 nodes, then you might find that the offsets topics was created with replicationfactor of 1. Run the following command `kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic __consumer_offsets` and see if in the first line of output it says "ReplicationFactor:1" or "ReplicationFactor:3".

Comment: Yes, the replication factor is 1. I will have to alter it

Comment: I was able to alter replicator factor following steps in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960767/how-to-change-the-replicas-of-kafka-topic). I have updated the replicas to node 1,2 for __consumer_offests and kafka elected node 1 as the leader. After killing node 1, the replicas are still node 1,2 and leader is 2. **How can I make kafka choose node 0 as replica as well?**.

Comment: If replication factor is 3 it should have replicas on all three nodes, and it shouldn't matter which one is the leader. Only an in sync replica can become the leader so see that ISR (In Sync Replicas) has all three nodes in the list

Comment: Thanks Hans. I had skipped node 0 in the replicas array when sending JSON to update replication factor. I will have to update it.