# Kafka cluster increasing replica factor doesn't work

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-cluster

Hi I run into a strange issue with increasing Kafka's replica factor when following the steps in this document: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_increase_replication_factor

The symptom looks like replica factor increase doesn't work at all.

Please help

**My Kafka setup is**

Kafka version: kafka_2.12-2.1.0

Server: hostname server-0 (192.168.0.1)

- Kafka Broker Id: 0
- Kafka Port: 9092
- Zookeeper Port: 2181

Server: hostname server-1 (192.168.0.2)

- Kafka Broker Id: 1
- Kafka Port: 9092
- No Zookeeper on server-1

Topics

- Number of Topics: 1
- Topic Name: DATA
- Number of Partitions: 1

**The DATA topic is created with replica-factor 1 from server-0 only first**

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic DATA`

result looks like

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic DATA
Topic:DATA  PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: DATA Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0`

after creating the topic, I produced some test message

`bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic DATA
message 1
message 2`

**Then the replica factor of topic DATA is increased to 2 by running commands in server-0 only**

below json file is used with Kafka-reassign-partitions.sh to increase the replica-factor

`{
    "version":1,
    "partitions":[ {"topic":"DATA","partition":0,"replicas":[0,1]} ]
}`

command line:

`bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --reassignment-json-file topics-to-expand.json --execute`

On the surface, the result looks good by describing the topics

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic DATA
Topic:DATA  PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
    Topic: DATA Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0,1`

I produced some more test messages here

`bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic DATA
message 3
message 4`

**However the problem arises when I tried to test from server-1**

Now I killed the kafka process from server-0 by

`kill -9 [kafka-pid]`

The problem happens when I run the console-consumer from server-1

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic DATA --from-beginning`

There are no messages shows up and the console just blocks at blank screen.

I think according to the document, I should be able to see the messages because replica is/was in-sync? No?

Describing the topic shows

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper server-0:2181 --describe --topic DATA
Topic:DATA  PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
    Topic: DATA Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 1`

Then I restarted the kafka process from server-0, the consumer console screen all of sudden shows all the messages in history

`message 1
message 2
message 3
message 4`

It looks like that the consumer from server-1 didn't consume any data from server-1 locally because topic data is not replicated to server-1. Instead, it still waits for server-0 to come back up to supply the data. Even server-1 is marked as leader.

Can anyone replicate my problem? 
I want to attach my properties but I don't know how to attach files in stackoverflow sorry about that...

Comment: Where is server-1 running? It looks like you're trying to run both on localhost:9092?

Comment: server-0 and server-1 are two independent amazon ec instances, you can think of them as 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2. The Kafka processes run on barebone servers, no docker containers involved.

Comment: You really should not immediately `kill -9` any process... Just `kill pid` to gracefully shut it down, and if it doesn't stop, then -9 it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Killing node with \_\_consumer\_offsets leads to no message consumption at consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855962/killing-node-with-consumer-offsets-leads-to-no-message-consumption-at-consumer)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by this post and figured out why.

[Killing node with __consumer_offsets leads to no message consumption at consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855962/killing-node-with-consumer-offsets-leads-to-no-message-consumption-at-consumer)

The reason of my above symptom is because default `offsets.topic.replication.factor=3` but I only have 2 brokers (nodes) in the cluster. When Kafka first created `__consumer_offsets` topic, it fails back to `offsets.topic.replication.factor=1` silently (yaks).

Changing `offsets.topic.replication.factor=2` in property file solves above problem. (yes tested!)